# Is there a simple player reference for Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, new-players

I've got a few new players wanting to try out *Pathfinder*, so thought I would run the *Rise of the Runelords* adventure to ease them into it. To help, I'd like to give them a simple double-sided reference, with non-combat activities on one side and combat actions on the other.

Something that explains the phases of a **Round**, what they can do in their **Turn**; **Standard** and **Movement** actions, line-of-sight, cover, etc.

For non-combat, there'll be things like natural **HP** recovery, travel speed, usual cost of supplies, an overview of *Golarion*, crafting costs, etc.

Is there a commercial product available, or has some kind soul of the community put something together that a small donation can secure?

EDIT:

Found this via the *Paizo* forums.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder2e/comments/eeyyxi/cheat_sheet_actions_and_activities_in_pathfinder/

Which is great for action/activity costs, but is probably more than I need at the moment, and has less of the simplest terms and explanations. The new players won't even know what a **Full-Round-Action** is.

Comment: "Full-Round-Action" does not appear anywhere in the sheet you linked, as far as I can see. And afaik its also not even something that exists in Pathfinder 2e anyway. (I only play the german version, so maybe it's in the books somewhere). And there is no such thing as "Standard" and "Movement" Actions. Are you maybe asking about Pathfinder 1 and not 2?

Comment: There's no language for full-round actions in the English version of PF2e either. They'd be called 3 action activities, and even then wouldn't be a full round if you're quickened. This is a PF1e question. That being said, the link is to the PF2e subreddit - if you're not aware OP, *Rise of the Runelords* is written for the first edition of Pathfinder, not the second. If the second edition (PF2e) is what you want, check out the Beginner's Box, or a second edition AP like Abomination Vaults.

Comment: OK. I see. I was thinking in terms of Pathfinder 1E, not realising that Pathfinder 2E has fundamentally changed the way the Turns work. Guess we'll all be learning then.

Comment: @SiBrit feel free to ask questions here if you stumble across any unclear rules, we're happy to help!